# How to change the language of new Captcha-Recaptcha

Tags: recaptcha

Can anyone give me an example about to change to italian ReCaptcha questions and answers?

I found the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=it" />
```

But no idea where to put it and all attempts to place it on my contact form failed.

It always speaks english only.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you paste the code you have, it makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Script tags usually go in the head section, between the `<head>` and `</head>` tags, or just before the body closing tag, `</body>`.

However, you also need to add a tag in the form for the ReCaptcha to be show.

This code will display the ReCaptcha in Italian:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>reCAPTCHA demo: Simple page</title>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=it" async defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="?" method="POST">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key"></div>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

You need to replace the `data-sitekey` attribute with your own API sitekey.

Comment: @gigog: Did this help you?